# Domain masking and wordpress

Tags: domain, domain-mapping

Hello I have registered a domain mysite.gr and connect it with domain masking with a site I had created on 000webhost.com mysite.000webhost.com. The problem is that when I am trying to access an article of the site the url on the browser remains the same mysite.gr it does not change to mysite.gr/article/001

Comment: Is it really a domain mapping, and not just a frame?

Comment: a frame? I do not understand what you mean